# Using NSFetchedResultsController in Swift 2.0

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift2, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to do an automatic update in a `UITableView`.

I ask here, and found a possible answer. I try to use the `NSFetchedResultsController` to update the `UITableView`.

I read several tutorials and tips, but none corresponded to my project with Swift 2.0. I need help with this, someone could post an example of using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question..

Do you want to update the core-data informations or just the `UITableView` ?

But if you want to update the `UITableView`, you just have to do :

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```